# Passport JWT returns unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I checked a lot of answers here but nothing helps. Can't find what's wrong with the passport setup, here is the code:

Server.js

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import passport from "passport";

dotenv.config({ silent: true });

import passportFunction from "./config/passport";

passportFunction(passport);

import routes from "./routes";

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB);
mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected");
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.use("/api", routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("App running on port 3000");
});
```

Passport.js

```js
import passportJWT from "passport-jwt";
var ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
var JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

import User from "../models/user";

export default function(passport) {
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
      User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.id }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false);
          // or you could create a new account
        }
      });
    })
  );
}
```

I think it's problem with importing passport strategy since I used ES6. Before that I used 'require...', but can't figure out it, I found the answer here, how to import and pass parameters to function, it doesn't show any errors but doesn't work..

I'm using it like `router.post('/url', passport.authenticate('jwt') ....`

Comment: Can you show how the client is passing the token?

Comment: I'm testing it with Postman, at least, it should work there.. Added content-type, authorization headers and body..

Comment: Can you show what your auth header looks like?

Comment: `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOi...`

Answer (score 0):

If you come across with the problem, here is the solution, I copied the strategy from passport-jwt docs, and it didn't work because of this line: 
`User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.id }, function(err, user)...`

It has to be `{ _id: jwt_payload._id }`